# Is this a positive or negative sentence?

Tags: construction

I heard a sentence like this:

> *How will Bill ever know that?*

Can someone tell me if this is a positive or negative sentence and what are the guidelines to decide which it is?

Comment: It is neither positive nor negative, intrinsically. It could be either depending on context.

Comment: It is neither; it is an ***interrogative*** sentence.

Comment: An interrogative sentence can be a reproof or an expression of approval, which is what I presume the OP means by positive or negative. Don't you know that? (An example of a reproof.)

Comment: I think you might want to expand on how you would define positive and negative.

Comment: @JamesJiao I would assume they meant as per grammatical polarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an affirmative (or "positive" if you prefer) sentence in the interrogative mood, though it is likely used sarcastically.

The sentence itself is affirmative because it doesn't use negation in the way that "Wouldn't Bill know that?" or "Are you not happy with this answer?" would.

But the *ever* suggests that the person asking can't envision a situation in which Bill could know. It could be that (due to prior conversation) they're prepared to believe that Bill could learn the information in question but still don't see how. It would more often be the case that what the speaker is really trying to express is "Bill will never know that".

This doesn't change the polarity of the sentence itself from being positive/affirmative though.

We can't describe an implied statement as having grammatical polarity, because grammar refers to what is expressed not what is implied (though it will affect what is implied). If we were to express the implied view directly rather than with sarcasm we could use either negative ("Bill will never know that") or affirmative ("Bill will forever be ignorant of that") clauses to express the same thing.

Edit: Sorry, I missed the bit about how to decide if a sentence (and by extension, a clause, verbal phrase, etc.) is negative or positive.

The simple rule is that they are all positive (also called *affirmative*) unless they are explicitly negated by one of the following:

1. "No." as a sentence on it's own is a negative sentence, the full meaning of which is to negate the suggestion of the question or statement it is in response to.*
2. The use of *not* or the contraction of *not* into *-n't*.
3. The use of *never*, *neither*, *nobody*, *none*, *nor*, *nothing* or *nowhere* to invert the meaning there would be without them or with the positive equalivent (*ever*, *either*, *anybody/somebody/everybody*, *some/all/any*, *or*, *anything/everything/something*, *somewhere/everywhere/anywhere*.

As stated above, the same idea can be expressed in an affirmative or negative clause: "I don't know anything about modern Croatian poetry" is negative but "I am completely ignorant about modern Croatian poetry" is affirmative, but both mean the same thing. It's not what is expressed that makes it negative or affirmative, but *how* it is expressed.

Note that a sentence can mix affirmative and negative parts:

> I am going to go on holidays in the winter, not the summer.

*An interesting side-effect of the fact that Irish, Scottish Gaelic, Manx and Welsh all lack a direct equivalent to one-word *no* and *yes* is that there is a greater tendency in Ireland, Man, Wales and the areas of Scotland that spoke Gaelic more than Scots (all predominantly English-speaking today) to use a full clause response even in English. E.g. "I am" or "I am not" rather than "Yes" or "No", or else to double-up; "I am, yes" or "I'm not, no". Sadly, "I don't, no" sounds like "I don't know" to customs officers from outside those areas, and you never want a customs officer to hear you say that you don't know if there are electronics in your bag.

Comment: Thanks for such elaborative answer. The fact that you mentioned that it is said sarcastically is exactly what i had in my mind. Also the usage of word "ever" affirms the belief. You guessing that it might be because of the prior conversation is all setting the context for my question, which i omitted intentionally. Thanks a lot for letting me know so many things in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only statements can be negated, because [only statements can be true or false](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). Neither of the following non-statement sentences, for instance, can be said to be either true or false:

- *Did you vote for Reagan?*
- *Please open the door.*

However, non-statements **can** contain negative triggers -- [structures, phrases, or words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) that license the occurrence of [Negative Polarity Items](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) -- but that's a different thing.

**All** questions, for instance, are negative environments, in the sense that NPIs like *anybody, ever*, and *yet* can occur grammatically in them, even though they can't in the corresponding statements.

- *Did he see anybody in the window?*
- **He saw anybody in the window.*
- *When did you ever see that?*
- **I ever saw that yesterday.*
- *Has he arrived yet?*
- **He has arrived yet.*

Comment: Really? I've always taken interrogative and imperative statements as being affirmative or negative in terms of the way they are expressed, so I'd have said "Did you not vote for Reagan?" and "Please don't open the door!" were each negative where yours are affirmative.

Comment: Negative in form, but not negative in meaning. (I doubt, parenthetically, that a native speaker who expected a serious response would say _Did you not vote for Reagan?_, without special stress on some word in the sentence. Of course, questions with overt negatives like _Didn't you vote for Reagan_ can occur, so they're used. Generally they indicate the speaker's belief that you **did** vote for Reagan, however, so they're very much not negative semantically.

Comment: Yes, I'd always taken "negative" to be about the form, considering that you can negate a meaning without a negative form and "the water was cooled below zero degrees to freeze it" and "the ice was warmed above zero degrees to melt it" are exact opposite in meaning and both positive.